# Access denied on WaitForSingleObject on an event created from managed code

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, synchronization, ipc

How do I create a named event object in C# so that I can wait on it in separate C++ process?

My simplified C# code of process A:

```
EventWaitHandle evt = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "eventName");
EventWaitHandle.SignalAndWait(evt , <other event>);
```

And simplified C++ code of process B:

```
HANDLE hEvt = OpenEvent(
    EVENT_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE,  // access
    FALSE,               // do not inherit handle
    TEXT("eventName")
);

if (hEvt == NULL)
{
    printf("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    //error out
}

DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hEvt, INFINITE); 
switch (dwWaitResult)
{
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        //Signalled  - all good
        break;

    // An error occurred
    default:
        printf("Wait error (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        //error out
}
```

When I run (or debug) this code, the event is created (C#) and opened (C++) just fine. However I get error 5 (Access Denied) during WaitForSingleObject.
Adding 'Global\' prefix does not help (nor does adding EventWaitHandleSecurity argument in C# code that allows full control to all build in users).

What I am doing wrong? Is this supposed to work at all?

**Edit** Fixed the C++ by adding SYNCHRONIZE desired access. Credit for pointing this out goes to Hans Passant - [Access denied on WaitForSingleObject on an event created from managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791666/access-denied-on-waitforsingleobject-on-an-event-created-from-managed-code#comment74624457_43791666)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c9z2kt(v=vs.110).aspx Check the `eventSecurity` parameter

Comment: You asked for EVENT_MODIFY_STATE but that's not what you are doing.  You have to use/include SYNCHRONIZE.

Comment: @HansPassant As allways - short but perfect answer! Mistake was on my side for misreading the docs. Thanks Hans - please post your comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: I doubt I can see all of the code, just show us what you ended up doing to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answering myself as there is no other answer to accept, but it is not unanswered question any more).

[As pointed out by Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791666/access-denied-on-waitforsingleobject-on-an-event-created-from-managed-code#comment74624457_43791666) - Issue was in incomplete desired access flags of OpenEvent call.
The code in question is already accordingly fixed and works fine.