# Can't get Event notification between processes in winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm learning about Events synchronization in winapi. I took as example 2 processes 1 that creates, sets an event. Also it opens the 2nd process. The 2nd program that waits to be notified and print a message. Here is the code:
Program 1:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

HANDLE hEvent;

int main()
{
    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, "Ev");
    if (hEvent == NULL) {
        printf("Error event");
        return -1;
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    if (!SetEvent(hEvent)) {
        printf("Setevent error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!CreateProcess("G:\\testing\\test1_2\\x64\\Debug\\test1_2.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        printf("Cannot create process.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    CloseHandle(hEvent);
}
```

Program 2:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

HANDLE hEvent;

int main()
{
    hEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, "Ev");

    DWORD res;
    while (true)
    {

        res = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
        if (res == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            printf("Hello world!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hEvent);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't make it work to print the text. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT :** As I can't answer this question I found the issue. Please check comments bellow and follow the link that @RaymondChen provided. Change `EVENT_MODIFY_STATE` to `EVENT_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE` and use a `Sleep` (first process is dying and Event disappear as @RbMm pointed out) after `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Check the error code from WairForSingleObject. You opened the handle with `EVENT_MODIFY_STATE` but WaitForSingleObject requires SYNCHRONIZE.

Comment: @RaymondChen If I put SYNCHRONIZE instead of EVENT_MODIFY_STATE I'm getting a linking error. I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: *I'm getting a linking error.* - really ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access denied on WaitForSingleObject on an event opened with EVENT_MODIFY_STATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791666/access-denied-on-waitforsingleobject-on-an-event-created-from-managed-code)

Comment: but faster you got `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` from `OpenEvent` and `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` from `WaitForSingleObject`, because you close this event in first process, possible before (undefined) second process try open it. then no sense call `SetEvent` - when you can from begin create event in signaling state

Comment: @RbMm yea I did a mistake, but still doesn't work with SYNCHRONIZE.

Comment: i explain why not work - to many mistakes. + you not check return codes of api

Comment: @RbMm I was trying to reproduce a small example but I will check for errors. I just used Sleep to keep the first process alive. Thanks

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for your help. I figured out

Comment: Please post an answer and accept it.